# appbundle being generated with the empty String.fromEnvironment

Tags: flutter, google-play-services, flutter-release, flutter-debug, flutter-run

I'm storing some settings in `String.fromEnvironment('CONFIG_EX')`, when I run the app in `Debug` or `Profile` mode everything works normally, but now I launched it on the PlayStore in Open Test and it's returning a 403 error and I realized that the compilation generated the empty variables.

it's more or less like this in my run settings:

```
--dart-define=CONFIG_EX=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I'm generating my appbundle this way:

```
flutter build appbundle
```

Is there any way to generate this appbundle with the run settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend build commands with extra parameters.

Android:

```
flutter build appbundle --dart-define=CONFIG_EX=xxx
```

iOS:

```
flutter build ios --dart-define=CONFIG_EX=xxx
```